# import chat.server not found 

Tags: java, client, chat, rmi

When I develop an RMI server, I use:

```
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteServer;
import java.rmi.server.StubSecurityManager;

import chat.server.*;
```

But when I compile the Java file, an error occurs that says:

> Class java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteServer not found in import. import
>   java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteServer

and also error with `StubSecurityManager`. Please help me work out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using an old code written in  JDK1.1 trying to compile using newer version of JDK.

You need to make following changes.

```
java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteServer -> java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject
java.rmi.server.StubSecurityManager -> java.rmi.RMISecurityManager
```

Source:
http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.api/browse_thread/thread/c768d6617f80eedd/4edf4acebd2ce575

Comment: tejaspillai

Thank you
When I try to compile the code again, I have appeared error 
it say  "package chat.server dose not exist " 
how can i solve this error if i really import chat.server.*; :(
my version of JDK. is 6 :(
I really do not know what I can do ,pls help me

Comment: can you share the code so that i can understand the question clearly.

Comment: h do not now where my reply  :(
i am I'm trying to compile  the code on this page 
http://www.webbasedprogramming.com/Java-Expert-Solutions/ch37.htm
it is client server Application "chat "